# Is there any way to make a shell script alias automatically?

Tags: shell, unix, packaging

I am trying to automate directory creation and file editing/creation through shell script. I have been sucessful in this but cannot figure out how to pakage the script, i.e. when I want to run the script this is what I enter, also this has to run from the file the program it is in.

```
. autoinit.sh -n <name> -c <project>
```

This issues can be solved if I alias this in `~/.bashrc` but I want to share this on GitHub and people have to follow a lot of information to get up and running.

What script can I add to make the following possible? In ideal instance people should be able to clone the repo and type in the following to start the script:

```
autoinit -n <name> -c <project>
```

Comment: Your question title seems to have very little to do with what you've posted in the question body. You may want to improve your question before it's closed as unclear or for some other reason.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+package+manager https://github.com/bpkg/bpkg https://github.com/bpm-rocks/bpm etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Self-Extracting Shell Archives

For managing self-extracting shell archives, you could use the [shar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) and unshar commands. Both are usually standard utilities on Linux and BSD, but your mileage may vary.

### See Also

Detailed usage instructions are available in the [GNU shar utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/manual/sharutils.html) manual. If you're using some other variant, the man pages (if present) will help.